# ESLint / Prettier / Husky indent problems in React-Native app

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint, prettier

I have a problem, when I commit, I have Husky which checks for indentation errors / usual errors (like props are not used.... etc). My app is a TypeScript React-Native app.

I am getting the following:

```
  25:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2      indent
  26:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 0      indent
  27:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2      indent
  28:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 4      indent
  29:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6      indent
  30:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6      indent
  31:1   error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8     indent
  32:1   error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8     indent
  33:1   error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8     indent
  34:1   error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8     indent
  35:1   error  Expected indentation of 10 spaces but found 8     indent
  36:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6      indent
  37:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 4      indent
  39:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 4      indent
  40:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6      indent
  41:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6      indent
  42:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6      indent
  43:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 6      indent
  44:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 4      indent
  45:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2      indent
  46:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 0      indent
```

My VSCode is set to 2 spaces,

My `eslint.rc` rule is `"indent": ["error", 2]` and my `prettier.rc` is set to `"tabWidth": 2,`
I don't understand why it's giving errors, the code is formatted as it should be. I even ran prettier myself `command-shift-f` on Mac.

Any ideeas?

Answer (score 1):

[Prettier documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html) states that

> Whatever linting tool you wish to integrate with, the steps are
>   broadly similar. First disable any existing formatting rules in your
>   linter that may conflict with how Prettier wishes to format your code.
>   Then you can either add an extension to your linting tool to format
>   your file with Prettier - so that you only need a single command for
>   format a file, or run your linter then Prettier as separate steps.

In your case, I would suggest 
1. Add `prettier` to the end of the extends array in eslintrc to disable the formatting rules

```
{
  "extends": ["prettier"]
}
```

2. Then you can combine husky with [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) to run pre-commit hooks for your staged files.
   For example:
   in `package.json`, define husky

   "husky": {
     "hooks": {
       "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
     }
   }

create `.lintstagedrc.js` in root folder

```
module.exports = {
  '*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}': ['eslint'],
  '*.+(js|jsx|json|yml|yaml|css|less|scss|ts|tsx|md|graphql|mdx)': ['prettier --write'],
};
```

It will run eslint to check linting errors and then format your code with prettier.

Comment: Didn't work. Apparently, for whatever reason this weird occurance was on a single branch. I just asked a colleague to push the part of code I wrote for me and we merged and then it was all good. We had the same settings.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using typescript

```
extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",

        //this will block eslint showing conflicting prettier errors. prettier will handle it
        "prettier",

        // if eslint-config-prettier version is before 8.0.0, include those two lines, if not exlude
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
        "prettier/react"
    ],
```

To use this plugins, install `npm i -D eslint-config-prettier`

Instead of creating a separate file, you could add whose to package.json under scripts:

```
 "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint",
      "**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx}": "prettier --write"
  },
```

`lint-staged` will lint only the staged files, instead of entire project which would take a lot of time. With "prettier --write", link-staged will correct the files and add them to the staging area